# How to generate multiple chart in sql server report

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a scenario in which user select multiple products and select multiple locations now if user select 2 products and 2 locations i want to generate 2 X 2 = 4. 4 charts and show each product particular location daily prices in chart? Daily prices of products per locations are saved in database. I want to know can i generate charts like this and how?

[image]

for example If this is the data, I want to generate Apple location F chart then Apple location M chart then Mango Location M chart and last Mango location F chart. I am using sql server 2008 R2 with C#

Answer (score 1):

Use a tablix with locations as the row group and product as the column group. Then put a chart in the data cell. The tablix will slice up your data and the chart can then have date as the category axis and price as the data.

Comment: Exactly. If you're struggling to understand the tablix(matrix) control, think of it as a 'design time pivot table'. You see the columns and rows in the report as you would with a normal pivot, but you won't see it rendered as such until you run the report.